# Qunit+SinonJs spy.calledOnce in setTimeout is undefined

Tags: javascript, qunit, sinon

I have a problem understanding the behaviour of sinonjs spies.

This is my test:

```
asyncTest('sinon async spies test', 
function() { 

    var pApi = 
    { 
        product: function(id, options) { 
            var d = { o: 'a result' };
            options.success(d);
            return d;
        },
    };

    this.spy(pApi, 'product');
    pApi.product(1, { success: function(data) {} });

    //Assertion 1
    ok(pApi.product.calledOnce, 'product API called: ' + 
        pApi.product.calledOnce);

    setTimeout(
            function() { 
                //Assertion 2
                ok(pApi.product.calledOnce, 
                    'product function called once (calledOnce: ' +   
                     pApi.product.calledOnce + ')');
                start();
            }, 1000);

});
```

Running the above test with qunit and sinonjs (via sinon-qunit), I pass Assertion 1 but fail the Assertion 2 (within the setTimeout callback). In fact, when we log the value of `pApi.product.calledOnce` in the console (as is done via the assertion's message), it is `undefined`.

Note: I have this at the top of my test file:

```
sinon.config.useFakeTimers = false;
```

Could anyone explain this curious behaviour? Shouldn't `pApi.product` within the setTimeout callback and without both have `calledOnce` as a valid property of the spy?

**Updated**

Based on http://api.qunitjs.com/asyncTest/, I figured out why the above behaviour is displayed.

`asyncTest` does not run the testrunner until the `start()` function is called. The above test worked when I changed `this.spy(pApi, 'product')` to `sinon.spy(pApi, 'product')`. Apparently there is a dependency on whether `test` is used instead of `asyncTest`, which affects when the `this.spy` method is run.

Will need to actually look at the sinon, qunit and sinon-qunit code in order to figure this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the spy to a variable, and use that to assert calledOnce:

```
asyncTest('sinon async spies test', function() { 
    var pApi = { 
        product: function(id, options) { 
            var d = { o: 'a result' };
            options.success(d);
            return d;
        }
    };

    var pApiSpy = this.spy(pApi, 'product');
    pApi.product(1, { success: function(data) {} });

    //Assertion 1
    ok(pApiSpy.calledOnce, 'product API called');

    setTimeout(
            function() { 
                //Assertion 2
                ok(pApiSpy.calledOnce, 
                    'product function called once');
                start();
            }, 1000);

});
```

This will pass both assertions. I think the problem has to do with Sinon restoring the method at the end of the test function, even though QUnit is still waiting for `start()` to indicate the test is complete.  When your timeout function is invoked, `pApi.product` is no longer a spy object, so it does not have a calledOnce property. Setting the spy to its own variable allows you to keep a handle on it until the timeout is called.